# Javascript - unexpected behavior in dates calculations

Tags: javascript, date, var

I'm a newbie and recently started to read Beginning Javascript, by McPeak and Wilton. The authors propose an exercise about dates calculation. This is the exercise

> Using the Date type, calculate the date 12 months from now.

I tried to solve it with this code

```
//gets today's date
    var today = new Date(); 

//this line transforms the date in milliseconds    
var daysAsMilliseconds = 1000* 60 * 60 * 24 * today.getDate(); 

//creates a new Date object 
    console.log(new Date(today.setDate(365) + daysAsMilliseconds));
```

The result I get here is correct(August 11th 2018).

Later, I wonder if it was really necessary to create 2 variables and tried this solution:

```
var today = new Date(); 
console.log(new Date(today.setDate(365) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * today.getDate())));
```

Here the solution was incorrect. The console showed August 31 2018. Why?

If necessary, [here you will find the repl.it with the code](https://repl.it/KGPj/1)

Comment: Are you sure ?? try this : console.log(new Date(new Date().setDate(365) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * new Date().getDate())));  Gives expected output

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets, not repl.it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I didn't know Stack Snippets. Thank you for introducing me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call *setDate*, before you call *getDate* , therefore *getDate* will always return 365. Simply swapp it:

```
new Date((1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * today.getDate()) + today.setDate(365))
```

Or its may easier to work with months directly:

```
today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 12);
var intwelvemonths = today;
```

Comment: Not just "easier" doing it with months, doing this via milliseconds and `setDate(365)` is actually **wrong**; your months approach (or Pointy's year approach) is the right way to do it. Doing it with milliseconds fails to allow for various vagaries in terms of the length of a year (such as leap years).

Comment: Leap years, leap seconds, daylight/summer time shifts, etc. Computing time ranges with "seconds math" is always risky :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add 1 to the year:

```
var yearFromNow = new Date();
yearFromNow.setYear(yearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
```

Setting the date to `365` makes no sense; `.setDate()` is for day-of-month, so setting it to that constant moves the date a year (usually) from the last day of the previous month. And you don't need to do any other math outside of the date API; just increment the year, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `today.setDate(365)` before you're adding the results of `today.getDate()`: `today.getDate()` will give the date that you set, not today's date.

Changing the order of operations will do the trick:

```
var today = new Date(); 
new Date((1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * today.getDate()) + today.setDate(365));
```

Comment: Except that not all years are exactly 365 days long.

Comment: That's true, but the root of OP's issue isn't a trick of the calendar, it's the order of operations.

Comment: Yes, it looks that working with dates is subtler than I imagined, as Noah Sussman explains in this [post](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a package as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) because it manage a lot of date formats, and it has very good implementations for date managing.

Using moment js for add.

`moment().add(Number, String);`

Example

```
var m = moment(new Date(2011, 2, 12, 5, 0, 0));
m.hours(); // 5
m.add(1, 'days').hours(); // 5
```

For more docs see [moment().add() docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)